# GitLab Time Tracking does not show on issue sidebar for any issue

Tags: time, gitlab, tracking

I am on “GitLab Enterprise Edition 11.6.0-ee” I believe. That is what GitLab>Help tells me on gitlab.com.

I put this into an issues comment field:

/estimate 1d 3h

/spend 2h

When I click Preview GitLab nicely shows:

Sets time estimate to 1d 3h. Adds 2h spent time.

But the “Time tracking” menu on the right hand side does not update and keeps showing:

Time tracking
No estimate or time spent

I am the project maintainer, so I should have the permissions to set these times?

I have tried with and without a due Due date, which shouldn’t influence estimate and time spent.

I have tried setting estimate and time spent for another team member. This team member can not see any estimate and time spent neither in the comments nor in the issue sidebar.

Please , where do I go wrong. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Based on [documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/workflow/time_tracking.md) you're doing all correctly. Open a issue on gitlab-ce repository on gitlab.com, they probably can tell you what's the problem.

Comment: Thanks Sakura Kinomoto; I will try to do that asap.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the situation improves with GitLab 1.11 (May 2019)

> ### View time tracking in sidebar of board view
>
> Issue sidebars should be consistent in both board and issue views.
>
> GitLab is moving towards this consistency by introducing time tracking into the issue sidebar view while on an issue board.
> Simply navigate to an issue board, click on an issue to pull up the sidebar, and easily view time tracking information.

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/11_11/timetracking-boards2.png]

From [issue 31331](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/31331): see [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/time_tracking.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the time tracking within the board itself by using [GitLab Board Better](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gbb-gitlab-board-better/fjhimlhfidegbajaoaagkogellknammf)

[image: time tracking gitlab]